# Post programmatically to Facebook Market

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there an API to create new posts on the Facebook Market?

Comment: I expect @bhaidar means: http://apps.facebook.com/marketplace/

Comment: very true: facebook.oodle.com  thanks